# How to get iterate between all names and rank permutations in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, rank

I have a table that contains a customer_id, the product they purchased, the timestamp of the purchase, and the rank of the purchase order. I want to know if there is a way in SQL to get overall percentages for the different product combination ordering. Products can be purchased multiple times. Here are some example questions:

What percent of the time is Product B purchased after Product A?
What percent of the time is Product C purchased after Product A?
What percent of the time is Product C purchased after Product B?

I know I could write a bunch of case statements for the different permutations using `PRODUCT` and `RANK` columns but was curious if there was a more iterative type way in SQL. Also, I know it would be easier in a scripting language like Python but was curious about SQL.

```
CUST_ID PRODUCT     DATE        RANK
1000000 Product A   2019-07-30  1
1000000 Product B   2019-11-27  2
1000000 Product B   2020-08-15  3
1000000 Product C   2020-11-07  4
1000001 Product A   2019-05-21  1
1000001 Product B   2019-08-26  2
1000001 Product C   2020-06-26  3
1000002 Product A   2020-06-28  1
1000002 Product A   2020-10-30  2
1000002 Product B   2020-11-23  3
1000003 Product C   2021-07-03  1
1000004 Product C   2021-07-04  2
```

Comment: ABBA - what is the expected output, how many times B is after A and A is after B?

Comment: Yes @Serg. I like to get all percents for all permutations A->B, B->A, C->A, A->A, etc. There can be many permutations is the issue.

Comment: You can cross join products to get all possible 2-permutations. And use lead/lag to see those in your data ( AB, BB and BA in my example if I've got it right).

Comment: Working on that now @Serg thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL self-joins to compute these percentages. Here's a query to answer your example questions:

```
WITH combinations AS (
SELECT 
    t1.product AS product1, 
    t2.product AS product2, 
    COUNT(*) AS num_combinations
FROM 
    your_table t1 
INNER JOIN 
    your_table t2 ON t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id AND t1.rank + 1 = t2.rank
GROUP BY 
    t1.product, 
    t2.product
),
total_combinations AS (
SELECT 
    SUM(num_combinations) AS total
FROM 
    combinations
)
SELECT 
    product1, 
    product2, 
    num_combinations, 
    num_combinations * 100.0 / total AS percentage
FROM 
    combinations, 
    total_combinations;
```

Replace your_table with the actual table name in your database. This query first computes the count of each product combination (e.g., Product A followed by Product B, Product A followed by Product C, etc.) and then calculates the overall percentage for each combination. The percentages should answer the questions you provided, such as "What percent of the time is Product B purchased after Product A?".